# Android: onSizeChanged, an example?

Tags: android, size

I want to use onSizeChange to detect the height difference in a LinearLayout when the soft keyboard comes on screen. I want to issue fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN); at that point. An example would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand your question, but here is an example. You already know that you should use `onSizeChange`, but exactly where do you run into problem?

```
public class SizeChangingLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
    //...
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int xNew, int yNew, int xOld, int yOld)
    {        
        if (yNew < yOld) 
            fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN)
        else if (yNew > yOld) 
            fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP)

        super.onSizeChanged(xNew, yNew, xOld, yOld);

    }
}
```

`SizeChangingLinearLayout` is the root view of the `Activity`. It only changes when the keyboard comes on, on landscape mode, and so on.

Does this help?