# How to override OnSizeChanged of an android View

Tags: android, android-view

I need to hide/show some parts of an `activity` when the keyboard open/closes. Such method does not exist. By searching the internet I've found that I should override the `View`'s `onSizeChanged()` like this:
[Android: onSizeChanged, an example?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6262141/1477726)
.

But I have no idea where to put that line of code, nor how to assign it to an already defined `RelativeLayout`. So how to Override `onSizeChanged()`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no onSizeChanged, but there is onConfigurationChanged,

refer to this question for more details: [How to capture the "virtual keyboard show/hide" event in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312319/howto-capture-the-virtual-keyboard-show-hide-event-in-android)

Comment: Then use this method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534365/getting-the-dimensions-of-the-soft-keyboard , compare the heights of the screen to detect whether the keyboard is visible or no, but it's always recommended to stick to the standard method.